# Actions example server for MicroRos Arduino

Tags: arduino, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is the 'action's (vs publisher/subscriber and 'service' server/client) ready for use in MicroROS for Arduino? Is "https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro-ROS-demos/blob/galactic/rclc/fibonacci_action_server/main.c" the reference that can be used?

If above it true, then are the C++ examples under "https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro-ROS-demos/tree/galactic/rclcpp" also applicable? These examples seem to be pub/sub only, i.e. I do not see any examples of Service/Actions. Are there examples for Service/Actions as well that are elsewhere?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398501/actions-example-server-for-microros-arduino/) by [capablegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/99498/capablegh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, actions should be usable in Galactic in Arduino but you [will need to rebuild the library](https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_arduino#how-to-build-the-precompiled-library) in order to adjust [the number of entities required](https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_arduino/blob/b8ce03d5e6a93be32fe027502ebba42d81fae891/extras/library_generation/colcon.meta#L43-L48): Action server will need and an Action client will need 2 subscriptions and 3 service clients and Action server will need 3 service servers.

In any case, in Galactic you will need to use the RCL API, meanwhile, in Rolling (and in future releases) you have a new RCLC API, take a look [here](https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro-ROS-demos/blob/main/rclc/fibonacci_action_server/main.c).

Regarding the C++ examples, they are **not** applicable. The micro-ROS API is RCLC and it's C99. In fact those examples [has been deprecated](https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro-ROS-demos/pull/61).

---

Originally posted by [Pablogs](https://answers.ros.org/users/62986/pablogs/) with karma: 443 on 2022-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1